# Can Einstein-Rosen bridges - if they exist - link two points of which one lies outside of the observable universe of the other?

Tags: observable-universe, wormhole

So there's stuff very far away that is, due to expansion, accelerating away faster than the speed of light, so fast that its light will never reach us even with infinite time - and we can't reach that point even if we travel at the speed of light for all eternity. The comoving distance of where the universe becomes fundamentally unexploreable is, afaik, some 46.5 billion light years or so.

Theoretical Einstein-Rosen bridges could connect any two points of space-time. What I wonder though is whether this could also apply to points that are farther than these 46.5 billion light years apart, or whether this is a theoretical maximum distance for wormholes as well?

Whether the answer is yes or no - an explanation would be great :)

Edit: maybe I'm mixing up observable universe and hubble volume here - I mean the one relevant to the question of course :)

Comment: That's a very speculative question, and the honest answer is - we don't know. We've never observed a wormhole yet, and the science is quite hypothetical at this point. Theoretically, anything is possible.

Comment: but it's the same set of formulas that predict the possibility of wormholes that also predict the hubble volume/observable universe - so someone understanding this set of formula should probably be able to understand whether there is a mathematical relationship/constraint between the physical distance of the endpoints and the universe expansion / speed of light or if there is none